# ReferenceError: document is not defined , nodejs does not understand DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, eslint

Im trying to interact with a datamuse API using fetch()GET request and display it to the DOM.
But when i run node index.js im getting this error: ReferenceError: document is not defined.

```
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit');
```

i Googled it and got to know that nodejs does not understand DOM like how the browser does.

I tried fixing it:

1. with ESLint ,setting: env {browser: true}
2. installing JSdom package,then getting the error jsdom not defined

Could not figure ,please Help

Comment: Node.JS ***doesn't*** understand DOM, because there isn't any.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is a completely different Javascript environment from the browser.  It has a different library of functions available to it than the browser does.  For example, the browser has the ability to parse HTML and present the DOM API and it has the `window` object.  Node.js isn't  browser at all so it doesn't have those features.  Instead, it has TCP and HTTP networking, file system access, etc... the kinds of things you would typically use in a server implementation.

If, from node.js, you are trying to fetch a web page from some other server and then parse that HTML and then understand or manipulate the DOM elements in that web page, you would need a library for doing that.  Libraries such as [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) and [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) are popular tools for doing that.  Cheerio, parses the HTML, but does not run the Javascript in the page and then offers a jQuery-like API for accessing the DOM.  Puppeteer actually runs the chromium browser engine to parse the page and run the Javascript in the page to give you a fully representative DOM and can even do things like take screenshots of an actual rendered page.